# Unexpected ubuntu server down

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, syslog

I am using an Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS running ISP config that is hosted an VMware ESXi
I experienced an unexpected shutdown issue, and I'm trying to identify the source.
Upon checking the logs, I was unable to see the logs prior to the problem.
The logs are appear's only after the server runtime

Action taken by my side:

I used to perform Journalctl command for the particular period of time but unable to get the logs
1.mysql database service restarted
2.ntp service restarted

Note: i can't get any of the service ( Mysql,apache,etc) before the shutdown

Kindly provide the solution for to fix the issue and the rootcause

Comment: are you saying ALL your log files only contain logs since the most recent boot? - why have you tagged `ntp` for this question? what does NTP have to do with anything?

Comment: According to my presumption, NTP services cause log entries to terminate, so I tagged NTP.

 there are no log entries during an unplanned server shutdown. hence it's challenging to identify a problem

are you saying ALL your log files only contain logs since the most recent boot? -yes

Comment: Please read [this q&a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159221/how-do-i-display-log-messages-from-previous-boots-under-centos-7) to make sure you have logs enabled. If not, enable it. If you have it enabled, include them in your question.